# IIFE declation of angularJs filter

Tags: angularjs, filter, iife

I'm new to angularJs and trying to apply the "John Papa style guide" for angularJs coding.

I have the following html code :

```js
(function(){
  
  "use strict";
  
  angular
    .module("crm",[])
    .controller("studentList",studentList)
    .filter("firstLetter", function(){
        return function(input) {
          return input.substring(0,1);
        }
      }
      );
  

  /** controller */
  function studentList($scope){
    //some code
  }
})();
```

```html
<div class="container" ng-controller="studentList">      
     
{{"Hello"|firstLetter}}
      
</div>
```

This code works fine. Then i want to declare the filter  as following :

```js
(function(){
  
  "use strict";
  
  angular
    .module("crm",[])
    .controller("studentList",studentList)
    .filter("firstLetter", firstLetter);
  

  /** controller */
  function studentList($scope){
  //some code  
  }

  /** filter */
  function firstLetter(input){
    return input.substring(0,1);
  }
 
})();
```

and then i have got an error message when running:

> "Error: [$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/unpr?p0=inputProvider%20%3C-%20input%20%3C-%20firstLetterFilter

So i guess i need to inject the filter somehow, but i don't know how to do it. Any ideas ? 
Thanks !

Comment: Actually i just changed the js code into  :

  /** filter */
  function firstLetter(){
      return function(input) {
        return input.substring(0,1);
      }

    }

and it's working :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Actually, I just changed the JS code into:
>
> ```js
> /** filter */
> function firstLetter() {
>     return function(input) {
>         return input.substring(0,1);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> and it's working :-)

by [Serge Gilette](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7698567/serge-gilette) (OP)